# How to prevent access to a php file directly through url but redirect

Tags: php, html, url

I want my visitors to prevent a page success.php directly e.g: www.site.com/paypal/success.php but when paypal payment is complete it redirects to this page will show info. But not directly to this page before confirming paypal payment

Comment: you can rely on some session variables that are only set after successful payment

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not write-me-code service...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the right way to go about it.

You can always send people to the success page, optionally with a transaction id.

What you *can't* say though is if the payment succeeded. That's up to your payment provider. You'll likely have to wait for a message from them. In case of PayPal you can use [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/).

So don't rely on the success page to confirm a transaction, rely *only* on your payment provider.

Sessions or cookies should also not be used to track transactions. What would happen if I started 2 transactions simultaneously?

Comment: Best answer. Logical and correct! Also people using sessions or parameters. Wouldn't the best option be to check the referrer. We can simply hack to get to the success page unless we actually checked the referrer the correct way as well as using the IPN from PayPal

Answer (score -1):

Instead of setting your target URL in paypal as

```
http://...../success.php
```

set it as

```
http://...../success.php?secret=something-random-here
```

and then your `success.php` script shall check if `$_GET['secret']` exists and equals what you expect.

Comment: i want a code to be applied to secret then when i will next time enter the url and same secret code then it will show session over

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what your code looks like, but I would use sessions on payment processing which is then required on the success.php confirmation page.

```
<?php // transcation.php page

    // Should the payment be successfully authorized
    session.start();
    $_SESSION['successful_transaction'] = true;

?>


<?php //success.php

    if (empty($_SESSION['successful_transaction'])) die("Sorry, access denied");
?>
```